# Add animation to jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I've made some custom animation:

```
$(this).animate({opacity: '0'}, 200, function() {
    $(this).animate({height: '0'}, 200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Is there a way to add it to the jQuery function, so that I can call it like fadeOut() or slideIn() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is done in all [jQuery plugins](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/). The idea is to add your function to the `prototype` of jQuery, which is aliased as `$.fn`. You do it like this :

```
$.fn.myFadeOut = function(){
    return this.animate({opacity: '0'}, 200, function() {
        $(this).animate({height: '0'}, 200, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own jQuery function using `fn` property:

```
$.fn.removeElement = function() {
    return this.each( function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: '0'}, 200, function() {
            $(this).animate({height: '0'}, 200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
$( '#someElement' ).removeElement();
```

Comment: The `each` loop here is unnecessary.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly why do you think so? It will work correctly with Elements collection. For example if selector will be class, not id

Comment: Because jQuery's `animate` method can be applied to a collection of elements. `$('.foo').animate(...);` will animate *all* elements with the class "foo".

Comment: @antyrat animate will already iterate over all elements of the set